# Phonegap Minmum Android SDK version?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to install my Phonegap version 3.3.0 ontop an `Android 2.1`.

However in the logcat I get the following:

```
 ...(at Binary XML file line #13): Requires newer sdk version #10 (current version is #7)...
```

In my `Config.xml` I have this:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
```

So what is the minimum version, does phonegap not support `2.1` and only `2.3.3`?

Comment: Are you building locally or through build.phonegap.com?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Currently locally, but when I push to production I use build.phonegap.com

Comment: have you run `cordova build` since adding that line to `config.xml`?

Comment: I have, I always use `phonegap run android ` which will the build before installing.#

Comment: Correct. This maybe a support issue, will have to look into it further

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in `AndroidManifest.xml` in platforms>android folder.

This line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

android-versionCode: Internal Android Version Code. Sets the version code for the application. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. Default is generated from version as MAJOR * 10000 + MINOR * 100 + PATCH, or 1 if version cannot be parsed.

android-build-tool: Specifies which android build tool to use. Values can be gradle or ant. Defaults to gradle for android >= 5 or ant for android < 5.

android-minSdkVersion: Minimum Android SDK version. Corresponds to the usesSdk attributes in the AndroidManifest.xml file - more details are in the Android documentation. Defaults to 14 (Android >= 4.0).

android-maxSdkVersion: Maximum Android SDK version. Corresponds to the usesSdk attributes in the AndroidManifest.xml file - more details are in the Android documentation. Unset by default.

android-targetSdkVersion: Corresponds to the usesSdk attributes in the AndroidManifest.xml file -- an integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. More details are in the Android documentation. Unset by default.

android-installLocation: Where an app can be installed - defaults to internalOnly (as the Android SDK). auto or preferExternal allow the app to be installed on an SD card - this can lead to unexpected behavior. More details available in the Android documentation.

android-windowSoftInputMode: How the main window of the activity interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. More details, and possible values, available in the Android documentation.

for more information see this link 
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/